# How to create a CNN model using Pytorch from a csv file with 209 rows and 8 columns?

Tags: csv, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and after searching I could only find examples of CNN models for images only. My dataset is simply a csv file with 209 rows and 8 columns. I can not figure out how to pass input shape to the CNN model for my dataset.

Want a  simple CNN model using Pytorch for a csv file with 209 rows and 8 columns.

Comment: Hey Soumyashree, you might want to give the rest of the world more information on what you try to do. You also might consider using a fully connected NN because from what I guess you have normal tabular data which is usually not treated using CNN as you already found out yourself as CNNs have special properties that make them extra useful for image data. Moreover, 209 rows seems like a very small dataset for deep learning, so you might consider other types of analyses. Best, Jan

Answer (score 0):

**This is just general code that you will have to adjust based on your needs.**

First off, you want to read your csv file into a dataframe, which you will use pandas for:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')
```

Then you will split the features from the labels:

```
features = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
labels = data.iloc[:, -1].values
```

Then you can go ahead and perform some sort of normalization/standardization of the features to have them scaled. StandardScaler from sklearn is a good tool for this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
features = scaler.fit_transform(features)
```

You will need to have a certain shape. Given your data doing something like:

```
features = features.reshape(-1, 1, 8)
```

Now you can define a CNN model, define loss and optimization functions, and train the defined model:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 2, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 32 * 2)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

net = Net()
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 10 == 9:
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 10))
            running_loss = 0.0
```